# Passing environment variable to the COMMAND in CMake execute_process

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

I have the following CMake snippet that runs `COMMAND` in `WORKING_DIRECTORY`. I tried different ways to pass the environment variable  (`MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mbedtls/mbedtls/include`) but without success.

**The snippet that works (without env variable)**:

```
set(BUILD_CMD cargo build --features parsec-client/no-fs-permission-check)
set(WORKING_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/parsec_se_driver")

execute_process( COMMAND ${BUILD_CMD}
                 RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_ERROR
                 WORKING_DIRECTORY ${WORKING_DIR} )

if(NOT ${CMD_ERROR} MATCHES "0")
MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR "BUILD_CMD STATUS:" ${CMD_ERROR})
endif()
```

How can I pass the env variable to the `execute_process`?

If I write something like this:

```
execute_process( COMMAND MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mbedtls/mbedtls/include cargo build --features parsec-client/no-fs-permission-check
                 RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_ERROR
                 WORKING_DIRECTORY ${WORKING_DIR} )
```

or taking different parts to variables, or adding quotes, I get:

```
BUILD_CMD STATUS:No such file or directory
```

Comment: So I got to some solution, using set(ENV{VARNAME} ...} like this `set(ENV{MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mbedtls/mbedtls/include)` and the current question there is more convenient way pass env variable to the `COMMAND`. This structure works, the variable is passed. I will appreciate other solution than this work-around

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As recommended in the CMake mailing list [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-August/045665.html), your solution using [`set(ENV ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/set.html#set-environment-variable) is perfectly valid:

```
set(ENV{MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mbedtls/mbedtls/include)
execute_process( 
    COMMAND ${BUILD_CMD}
    RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_ERROR
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${WORKING_DIR}
)
```

You could also use CMake's command line [utility](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) to run the command in a *modified environment* using `cmake -E env`:

```
execute_process( 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env 
        MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mbedtls/mbedtls/include" ${BUILD_CMD}
    RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_ERROR 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${WORKING_DIR}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work also:

```
execute_process(
   COMMAND /bin/bash -c "CC=/usr/bin/gcc make"
)
```